# Inequality involving cardinality of subsets

Tags: co.combinatorics

This problem may require some higher math because it hasn't been solved on math.stackexchange.com so I am reformulating it here to see solution.

Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$, $|X|=3n$ and $S\subset 2^X$ such that:

(1) $A\in S\Rightarrow |A|$ is an odd number,

(2) $B\subset S\wedge |B|=2^{n-1}+1\Rightarrow |\bigcap B|$ is an even number.

Prove that $|S|\leq 2^n+n2^{n-1}$.

Comment: I recall a problem similar to this, which involved residents of a city named Oddtown.  You might try a web search.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.08.03

Comment: Any chance to learn which contest this is from?

Comment: "The Clubs of Oddtown" is item 3 in Matousek, Thirty-three Miniatures,  and it has some of the same flavor but concerns intersections of two sets, not $2^{n-1}+1$ sets. Similarly for Odd Clubs, Problem 59 in Bollobas, The Art of Mathematics. 

Comment: Joriki has posted an answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53750/circles-and-members